# How to take care of two DataContexts

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewmodel, datacontext

I've merged two programs, and now there are two DataContexts in my code. One is `DataContext = this;` and the other is `DataContext = _uiData;`. I'd like to keep the former, because there are many bindings relying on this DataContext (not shown in my code, though). For the latter, I changed it to `textBox.Text = _uiData.ToString();`, but it doesn't show anything. How would you take care of this kind of situation?

Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding.ViewModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> RightListBoxItems { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();
        private UISimpleData _uiData = new UISimpleData();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RightListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T1"));
            RightListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T2"));
            RightListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T3"));

            DataContext = _uiData; // How can I show this?
            //textBox.Text = _uiData.ToString(); // This doesn't show anything
            DataContext = this; // I'd like to KEEP this
            //RightListBox.ItemsSource = RightListBoxItems; // Works, but not for this time
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="253.5" Width="297.5">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="RightListBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding RightListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="20,20,20,100"/>
        <TextBox Margin="100,0,0,40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="22" Width="100"
                 Text="{Binding DoubleField, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel/UISimpleData.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding.ViewModel
{
    public class UISimpleData : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private double _doubleField = 5.5;

        public double DoubleField
        {
            get
            {
                return _doubleField;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_doubleField == value)
                    return;

                _doubleField = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DoubleField");
            }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "DoubleField":
                        {
                            if (DoubleField < 0.0 || DoubleField > 10.0)
                                validationResult = "DoubleField is out of range";
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown Property being validated on UIData");
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }

        public string Error { get { return "Not Implemented"; } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel/GraphViewModel.cs

```
namespace Both_ListBox_n_TextBox_Binding.ViewModel
{
    public class GraphViewModel
    {
        public string Text { get; }

        public GraphViewModel(string text) => Text = text;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make `_uiData` a property (e.g. `public UISimpleData UiData { get; } = new UISimpleData();`, then bind to it in XAML like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding UiData.SomeProperty}"/>`

Comment: Or move `RightListBoxItems` into the `UISimpleData` class and use this one as the `DataContext` for the window. Why do you want to keep `DataContext = this` instead of using a view model class?

Comment: @Clemens It works. Oh, that's how to take care of the situation ... I really really should have known this. Could you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it? If possible, please change the property name to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding UiData.**DoubleField**}"/>`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mm8 Firstly, I couldn't come up with such a solution, thank you. However, I'd feel something wrong if I did it because they are very different kinds. UISimpleData is for formatting double data, while RightListBoxItems is a list of items. I will use your method when two things have something in common.

Comment: @mm8 The reason why I want to keep `DataContext = this` is that some other lists, which are not included in my code, are also bound to `this`.

Comment: @IanHacker: Then move these to the view model as well.

Comment: @mm8 I've moved `public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> RightListBoxItems { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();` into `UISimpleData` and changed the Add statements like `UiData.RightListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T1"));`. **UiData.RightListBoxItems** ... here I feel something odd. But, I will definitely use this, when it's appropriate.